# Socket errors during selenium script

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I've recently made a selenium script to automate the process of generating test-data through a web-page in Firefox. The script is run from the command line where you can specify which types of test data you want and which in many cases makes the script take around 15 minutes to run.

During this time I quite often get the following error which kills any continuation of the script:

```
OSError: [WinError 10055] An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.
```

When using netstat -b I can see that Firefox is using tons connections (several hundred if not a few thousand) which are all in the state TIME_WAIT. I am therefore guessing that my script somehow expends all the available ports on the system, but I am not sure why.

Does every selenium action use its own connection? Do these connections then not close down until the script finishes running?

Comment: After looking up exactly what TIME_WAIT means it seems that this is the state every socket goes into after being closed and that it will stay in this state for 2MSL in order to ensure that re-using this port is safe. It therefore seems that selenium does indeed close connections, but it just creates too many connections in a short time interval. Is it possible to circumvene this behavior in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Switching from firefox to chrome seems to alleviate the issue somewhat.
You will still get a lot of connections in the TIME_WAIT state, but for some reason there seems to be a lot less connections in this state when using chrome

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same issue but with Chrome, did you figure out what could be the problem?